# Replace all dashes with underscores in filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to replace all occurrences of "-" with "_" in every file name in every sub folder of a directory.

This script does the job for a single folder:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=-"
Set "Replace=_"

For %%a in (*) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit
```

I tried doing a recursive search as follows:

```
For /R %%a in (*) Do (
```

but it returns a syntax error.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You need to change `set "File=%%~nxa"`, because `for /R` returns full paths and `ren` does not accept such for the new file name argument...

Comment: I would probably add `*-*` as the search mask inside the parentheses too, _otherwise you'd be running every unnecessary file through the loop too_.